# Double comparison using EXPECT_NEAR fails In QNX platform, but not in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, googletest, qnx

Test Case is like this:

```
EXPECT_NEAR(aVal, bVal, Delta);
```

In Linux: parameters values receptively like below:

```
aVal = 14.661583000000000 
bVal = 14.661583000000000 
Delta = 1.0e-15
```

Since, aVal and bVal are same, Hence this testcase passing on Linux.

In QNX:  What is happening I don't know,

```
aVal = 14.661583000000000
bVal = 14.661582999999998
Delta = 1.0e-15
```

Since, aVal and bVal are different, Hence this test case is fails.

```
NOTE: aVal, bVal and Delta are in double data type.
```

I found out if we increase delta values like "1.0e-10" Testcase will pass I don't want to do that, because I don't want to increase delta value here.

Could somebody explain me, why in QNX has like this kind of problem, can't it round the double value inside when it compare with other value ? And how to solve this problem explicitly ?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Use [`EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ (expected, actual)`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#floating-point-comparison) (it checks if the two values are within 4 ULP's from each other)

Comment: Do you really need 17 digits of precision? I ask because I have seen people measure things to 4 digits, then insist their results hold to 16 digits. This makes little sense as the result can't be more precise than the original measurements.

Comment: Agree, normally people will compare with 4 precision digits. But in our product they are comparing using delta value is 1.oe-15. so it is comparing with 15 digit precision.

Comment: My question is about how we can make round up precision value in double. To make this test case pass.